# Custom Arduino library not instantiating

Tags: c++, arduino

I have this code in my main arduino file:

```
#include <HIH4030.h>

HIH4030 humiditySensor(0);

float humidity;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  delay(1000);

  humidity = humiditySensor.sensorRH();

}
```

This is my HIH4030.h file contents:

```
#ifndef HIH4030_h
#define HIH4030_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class HIH4030{

public:
  HIH4030(int pin);
  float ratioHumidity();
  float sensorRH();
  float trueSensorRH(float temperature);

private:
  int _pin;
  float sample;
  float temperature;
};
#endif

//data sheet https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/SEN-09569-HIH-4030-datasheet.pdf
```

This is my HIH4030.cpp file contents:

```
#include <HIH4030.h>

HIH4030::HIH4030(int pin)
{
  _pin = pin;
}

/*
    gives humidity as a ratio of VDD
*/
float HIH4030::ratioHumidity(){
  //poll analogue in
  return analogRead(_pin); 
}

/*
    gives humidity as a percentage - numbers taken from datasheet
*/

float HIH4030::sensorRH(){
  //poll analogue in
  sample = analogRead(_pin)*5; //multiply by 5 as sample is a decimal of Vdd
  return (sample-0.958)/0.0307;
}

/*
    gives humidity adjusted for temperature (in degrees C) - numbers taken from datasheet
*/

float HIH4030::trueSensorRH(float temperature){
  float rh = sensorRH();
  temperature = temperature*0.00216;
  return rh/(1.0546 - temperature);
}
```

And when I compile I get this error:

```
Gathering compilation infomation...
Compiling sketch...
Cleaning...
Creating /Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.cpp.o...
Creating /Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.elf...
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.cpp:7: undefined reference to `HIH4030::HIH4030(int)'
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.cpp.o: In function `loop':
/Users/user/Documents/Arduino_Build/QuantifiedGarden/QuantifiedGarden.cpp:23: undefined reference to `HIH4030::sensorRH()'
[Stino - Error while compiling.]
```

I'm new to arduino, I'm using Stino Sublime Text 2 plugin. I have already converted a more complicated temperature sensor library I had written for a different platform in to Arduino and it worked perfectly - I can't see any difference between this and that other library but I must be missing something.

From what I can tell I have followed the How to make a custom class Arduino tutorial to the letter...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was some kind of cache error - deleting the Arduino Build folder sorted it out

Comment: You may also need to close and restart the IDE. which in effect likely will clear out its cache.

Comment: I had the same problem using Sublime Text Arduino plugin (Stino). As it turns out, there is a "Full Compilation" option in Stino preferences, and if you leave it checked, it will always compile everything (and thus will be immune to this obsolete cache problem). In the end I'm not sure if I solved the problem by checking full compilation back, or restarting Sublime Text, but you answer seems to be right on pointing the root problem cause. Thanks.